# Jquery hide/show not working with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to hide a result div. Modify it. Then Show it with animation.

I have the following:

```
$("#SearchButton").button().click(function() {
                $("#resultContainer").hide();
                $("#resultContainer").empty();
                searchResults();
                $("#resultContainer").show("slow");
});
```

Where `searchResults()` makes an ajax call to load some stuff into the div `#resultContainer`

However, even if I comment out the line `//searchResults();` I still end up with a blank div when I click the button.

However if I switch `$("#resultContainer").show("slow");` to `$("#resultContainer").show();` It works fine. But I want the animation. .show("slow") works fine elsewhere...

Update: I now have:

```
$("#SearchButton").button().click(function() {
                $("#resultContainer").hide(0);
                searchResults();
            });
```

And searchResults does the ajax call with the following callback:

```
//appending something to the div here              
$("#resultContainer").show(600);
alert("test");
```

I get the alert but the div never shows back up...

Comment: Does it work if you specify the milliseconds: `$('#resultContainer').show(600);` instead of `"slow"`?

Comment: or try to change the hide() to hide(0)

Comment: Could you do `console.log($.fx.speeds);` and paste the results?

Comment: @lonesomeday - where do I put that code?

Comment: @kraico626 Are you using a browser with a console (Chrome/Firefox with Firebug/IE Developer Tools?) If so, just type it into the console there.

Comment: @dave and tjrip I tried .hide(0) and .show(600) and then both at the same time. Same results each time.

Comment: @lonesomeday - i'm using IE however not sure about the Developer Tools part. do I need to download a special addon for that? I can do that if nessisary... not sure if it is already installed...

Comment: >>console.log($.fx.speeds);
LOG: [object Object]
undefined

Comment: The slim version of jQuery does not implement effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code can be improved, try this:

```
$(function() {
    var $resultContainer = $("#resultContainer");
    $("#SearchButton").click(function() {
        $resultContainer.hide();
        //$resultContainer.empty(); // BTW, no need to empty since the ajax will replace its content anyway!
        searchResults();
    });

    function searchResults() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "yourRequest.php",
            success: function(resp) {
                $resultContainer.html(resp);
                $resultContainer.show("slow");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

1. You don't need the empty the container since it's content will be replaced in the ajax call anyway and it's already hidden anyway!
2. Remove your `show` method to the ajax success callback
3. store the container in a var `$resultContainer` and use it for faster access.

And here's a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/NFpZu/4/).

Comment: My ajax call generates the data, then I use javascript to generate the html(the way I have it set up the contents of the dvi will not be replaced, but i could change it so that it would...), but anyways, I tried placing the .show("slow") in the callback and it still did not work...

Comment: still the same approach, in the success method and after your Javascript preparation of the returned data use `$resultContainer.html(finalResult);`

Comment: see my update. My point is that regarless of if i even chaneg whats in the div, it still doesn't show up!

Comment: As for the `show` method, are you using any other plug-ins on the page? what are the changes you are making on the DIV? what are the styling used on it? any absolute positioning?

Comment: well it's not actually a div, now that I look. It's the td of a table. so i created a div inside of the td of the table and it worked... aparently you can't do animation on td tags...???

Answer (score 0):

Your code showing the resulting div:

```
$("#resultContainer").show("slow");
```

should be chained in the callback of the ajax call; that's the only way you can be sure it will get executed **after** the ajax result is there. See the optionnal function callback at the end of the load() function. or the callbacks in the ajax functions of jQuery.

You could use something like a jquery queue to queue your events and get that queue paused. Then un-pause the queue in your ajax callback.

Or define some named functions and test that theses callbacks exists before calling them in the ajax callback.

Last thing, please store your selector results var $foo=$("#resultContainer") and use $foo variable after that and avoid calling the $() selector each time you need that div. This can speed up a lot your code.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, Two things: first, this is an issue even with the ajax call being commented out as a mentioned, and I did try placing the .show("slow") in the callback of the ajax call. Same effect... or lack there of

Comment: maybe you could send us the stuff done in the ajax callback. Maybe you destroy your #resultContainer div. If you inspect you DOM (html page) is you div there with a content and a display none ?. If you make an alert($("#resultContainer").length) do you get 1?